# onClick change state of child component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to update state between two components, my react knowledge is a bit rusty but this is how I've structured the components.

child component - makes  a get request to an API endpoint, and renders the data to my charting library

```
    export default class EmployerLearningNeeds extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          employerData: [],
        }
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData() // 
      }

      fetchData = () => {
        axios.get(fullAPI).then(res => {
          const apiResponse = res.data
          apiResponse.map(employer => {
            console.log('ChildResponse', apiResponse)
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
            employer.value = employer.value.toFixed(2)
            return employer
          })
          this.setState({
            employerData: apiResponse,
          })
        })

  }

    getOption = () => ({ data: this.state.employerData })

    render() {
     return( 
    <ReactEcharts option={this.getOption()}
    )}
```

parent component - renders my child component, button click should update the state of my child component

```
export default class InterviewInsights extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      employerData: [],        }
  }

testFunction = () => {
    axios.get(apiURL).then(res => {
      console.log('Parent response', res.data)
      this.setState({
        employerData: res.data,
      })
    })
  }
render() {
    return (
            <button href="#" onClick={this.testFunction}>
              click me
            </button>
            <EmployerLearningNeeds employerData={this.state.employerData} />
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything you pass from your parent component to your child component will be in `this.props`, not `this.state`.

From your code it looks like you want the parent to be able to fetch a different set of data and pass it down to the child for rendering.

Why bother having `fetchData` in the child if the parent is going to do the fetching and pass the data down anyway? (Apologies if I'm missing something - not 100% sure what you're trying to do.)

(Since `componentWillReceiveProps` has now been replaced with `static getDerivedStateFromProps`)

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    const apiResponse = props.employerData;
    apiResponse.map(employer => {
        console.log('ChildResponse', apiResponse);

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        employer.value = employer.value.toFixed(2);

        return employer;
    })

    return { employerData: apiResponse };
}
```

This will fire whenever the parent passes in a new set of data for `employerDetails`, process the data, and put the result in `this.state` (meaning you can keep your `render()` function as-is).

You could also just get rid of `componentWillMount`, `fetchData`, and `getOption` and change your `render` to the following:

```
render() {
    const { employerData } = this.props;
    const option = employerData.map(e => e.value = e.value.toFixed(2));

    return( 
        <ReactEcharts option={{ data: option }}
    )
}
```

Comment: sorry, I kinda found this a bit hard to follow...If  I  remove componentDidMount from my child component when the page is rendered my graph will be empty, which is not what I want, the purpose for the child component is to draw the graph and render generic data. The idea behind the fetchData inside my Parent component is that eventually it will be used as a filtering component, that fetches data and updates the state as needed.

Comment: Ah ok, understand. In that case, you'll need to either access the passed-down data via `props` or use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update the child's `state` whenever the parent passes new data down.